# How to provision nginx vhosts on Vagrant vm?

Tags: vagrant

I have a Ubuntu VM machine I'm running through Vagrant with `nginx` installed. It's pretty easy to ssh into the VM and setup a new nginx vhost whenever I need one. But what is the best practice for setting up nginx vhosts via Vagrant provisioning, or maybe using Puppet? Essentially I imagine some sort of config file(s) that sit in my host folder and when I provision, it parses these config files and creates a new vhost for me on the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html particularly https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html

With this you will be able to set anything you need on the vagrant VM.

Comment: Anible.com seems to be some sort of pay service. Where do I find Ansible playbooks?

Comment: Ansible sales Ansible-Tower (enterprise version with UI), ansible itself is free. Regarding playbooks you have to write them or you can download some at https://galaxy.ansible.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a vagrant plugin - [hostupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater). It can automatically update /etc/hosts and add virtual hosts pointing to your guest machine

Vagrant file configuration example:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.3.10"
config.vm.hostname = "www.testing.de"
config.hostsupdater.aliases = ["alias.testing.de", "alias2.somedomain.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a configuration management tool. Just write a template for nginx, apply variables as needed, reload nginx, and Bob's your uncle. Ansible is extremely easy to use, you can use ansible-galaxy to pull geerlingguy.nginx, which is a role that easily configures the basics for you.